# Why I can't call to public function in a Javascript namespace

Tags: javascript, function

I want to call to method `setupCanvas.Draw();` to draw rectangle.

And for some reason I can not call a function `Draw();` from out the scop `game.setupCanvas();` 
[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/dAvtS/8/)

```
window.game = window.game|| {};
game.main = function() {};      
game.setupCanvas = function(){

        var w = $(window).outerWidth();
        var h = $(window).outerHeight();
        myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(myCanvas);
        myCanvas.id     = "playground";
        myCanvas.width  = w * 0.8;
        myCanvas.height = h * 0.8;
        myCanvas.style.left= (w - myCanvas.width )/2 + 'px' ;
        myCanvas.style.top= (h -  myCanvas.height )/2 + 'px' ;     
        myCanvas.style.zIndex   = 10;
        myCanvas.style.position = "absolute";
        myCanvas.style.border   = "1px solid green ";
        this.ctx= $('#playground').get(0).getContext('2d');

       this.Draw  = function(){
         ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF";
         ctx.fillRect(150,75,150,75);
         ctx.fillStyle="#F0F0FF";
         ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    };
}();    
    game.setupCanvas.Draw();

​
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new instance:

```
var x = new game.setupCanvas();

x.Draw();
```

Also, this part is wrong:

```
 };
}(); // <--

game.setupCanvas.Draw();
```

You're immediately-invoking the function, which you shouldn't be doing. It returns `undefined` to `game.setupCanvas`. Take it away and your code should work.

Moreover, when you reference a the`ctx` property in your `Draw` method, you need to use `this.ctx`.

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/eEfJ7/)

Comment: @limelights You need to get rid of the `()` at the end of the function expression to `game.setupCanvas`

Comment: Yeah, I missed it. Also, he'll get a undefined on `ctx` since he's not referring to the `this.ctx`. You should update your answer! :)

Comment: @rotem Why are you changing it now? It works like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/eEfJ7/

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of `game.setupCanvas` is invalid since the self invoking function doesn't return anything so `game.setupCanvas` will be undefined. Make sure to return an object with your public methods like this.

```
return {
    Draw: function(){
      ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF";
      ctx.fillRect(150,75,150,75);
      ctx.fillStyle="#F0F0FF";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    },
    DrawSomethingElse: function(){
      ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF";
      ctx.fillRect(150,75,150,75);
      ctx.fillStyle="#F0F0FF";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
    }
};
```

Here is an update to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dAvtS/11/